# Regarding lz4mt compression and linux buffering issue

Tags: linux, caching, buffer, compression

I am using lz4mt multi-threaded version of lz4 and in my workflow I am sending thousands of large size files (620 MB) from client to server and when file reaches on server my rule will trigger and compress file using lz4mt and then remove uncompressed file. The problem is sometimes when I remove uncompressed file, I am not able to get compressed file of right size its because lz4mt returns immediately before sending output to disk. 
So is there any way lz4mt will remove uncompressed file itself after compressing as done by bzip2.

```
Input: bzip2 uncompress_file
Output: Compressed file only
```

whereas

```
Input: lz4mt uncompress_file
Output: (Uncompressed + Compressed) file
```

Below script sync command also not working properly I think.
The script which execute as my rule triggers is:

    **script.sh**

```
/bin/lz4mt  uncompressed_file output_file
/bin/sync
/bin/rm uncompressed_file
```

Please tell me how to solve above issue.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Author here. You could try the following methods

1. Concatenate commands with `&&` or `;`.
2. Add `lz4mt` command line option `-q` (suppress prompt), and `-f` (force overwrite).
3. Try it with original `lz4`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works fine for small no of files but if I transfer large no of files from client to server, again the size of the compressed file is less than what it should be.

Comment: I still could not understand your problem. Please answer the following questions to resolve your problem.
(1) Have you tried these three methods ? (`&&`, `-q -f`, `lz4`)
(2) What did you mean by "rule triggers" ?
(3) `lz4mt` could not accept multiple files. How did you pass "large no of files" to `lz4mt` ?